# Is pyautogui work in the ubuntu 18.04 server version with no display accessed via ssh?

Tags: python-3.6, pyautogui

When I am import pyautogui it gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from register import reg
  File "/home/nlp/Projects/face_recognition/register.py", line 12, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File "/home/nlp/miniconda3/envs/face_recognition_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 241, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/home/nlp/miniconda3/envs/face_recognition_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 223, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
  File "/home/nlp/miniconda3/envs/face_recognition_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
  File "/home/nlp/miniconda3/envs/face_recognition_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 62, in __init__
    display.Display.__init__(*(self, ) + args, **keys)
  File "/home/nlp/miniconda3/envs/face_recognition_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.socket = connect.get_socket(name, host, displayno)
  File "/home/nlp/miniconda3/envs/face_recognition_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Xlib/support/connect.py", line 76, in get_socket
    return mod.get_socket(dname, host, dno)
  File "/home/nlp/miniconda3/envs/face_recognition_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py", line 78, in get_socket
    raise error.DisplayConnectionError(dname, str(val))
Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display ":0": [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have tried this:

```
import os
os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0'
```

But still same error. According to one comment of to this link (https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/161) in github says it is not accessible remotely. I have tried **sudo xhost +** command but it gives me below error.

```
xhost:  unable to open display ""
```

Comment: This was discussed often on PyAutoGui github issue pages. Officially they don't support it. You can use dummy HDMI plug on your server somewhere to make it work. Or try this old [solution](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/124).

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir. @jupiterbjy